# How can I zip files in a HDFS directory using PySpark or shell?

Tags: python, pyspark, zip, hdfs

For example, I want to turn this

```
unzipped/
├── file1.csv
├── file2.csv
└── file3.csv
```

into this

```
unzipped.zip
 ├── file1.csv
 ├── file2.csv
 └── file3.csv
```

Using `ZipFile` as below I get the `FileNotFoundError`, even though I can access the file normally in other parts of the script.

```py
with ZipFile('unzipped.zip', 'w') as zipObj:
    for file in unzipped_files:
        df.write.csv(file+".csv")
        # I also rename the part-0000*.csv to file
        zipObj.write(file+".csv")
```

The other solutions I've found/tried use [java](/questions/tagged/java) or involve downloading the files to the local system, which is not suitable for my project.

Comment: by pyspark, i'm guessing you're doing it in spark-shell which is nothing but python (in simplest terms). what/how did you try zipping it that gave the error? did you check if the path you passed is accessible from that shell?

Comment: I editted the response adding some code, and the path is correct

Comment: `df.write.csv(file+".csv")` creates a folder named `file+".csv"`, not a file. are you zipping the file inside the folder or the folder?

Comment: I move that file to the right path after using `df.write`

Comment: i'm unable to replicate the issue using your code (if renamed correctly and paths are exact)